# Allow Public Likes But Not Comments?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I've create an account on Facebook which is going to be used primarily for marketing a non-profit that I work with.  The account is basically a character I'll be playing.  (Two accounts, actually, interacting with one another.)  But I'm not entirely sure how to set the privacy settings correctly, or if the settings I'm looking for are even possible.

Currently posts are viewable by everyone, which is exactly what I want.  (Since I don't expect people to "friend" these accounts.)  However, when viewing the posts/comments as non-friends there are no options to "like" or "comment."

The latter is good, I don't want anybody to comment on these posts.  But is there a way to allow anybody ("everyone" or "public" in Facebook terms) to "like" the posts/comments?  I've gone into the privacy settings and selected that "Public" can "View your future posts" and that "Everyone" can "See what others post on your timeline."  This is what made the posts public.  But is there a way to also allow people to "like" these posts?

Comment: Last time I tried 1 or 2 years ago, this wasn't possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, at least currently, no way to do this in Facebook.

If you want to get likes, you need to also deal with the interaction.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Worst case scenario is that I can write an application which will poll the comment threads and delete comments.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the interactions public.  It's still not letting non-friends and non-friends-of-friends comment/like.

Comment: Looks like I got it working with a status update instead of wall posts.  So if Person A posts to Person B's wall and they begin a discussion, I couldn't make it open for public comments.  But if Person A just posts a status update and Person B comments on that, it can allow public comments.

Comment: How do I allow both likes and comments anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen a number of profiles I’m not friends with, where I can like or react to posts or comments without being able to comment myself. 
I think it has to do with ‘who can like and comment on my public posts’ in settings, it’s not always possible to like something just because it’s public either.  But there is a trick I think it’s the friends of friends option in comment and like and friends only in comment. But there is definitely a way.